# how to generate a one-time token url after paypal payment?

Tags: php, url, paypal, token

I am creating virtual currency, say if a customer completes a payment so we can redirect them to a particular page say www.example.com/generate10coins,but it should be fool-proof since the customer can easily keep refereshing the page and keep creating more tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save a hashed token in your db after the payment.

then redirect the user to a url with the token as `$_GET` data

then when the page is first reached save the activity in the database as complete.

each time the page, e.g. `redirect.php?token=generate10coins`, is reached or refreshed make a db query to check if the token is complete or not.

Comment: but how to save a token exactly after payment?  I mean how to reference it back? one can simply refresh the page right?

Comment: thats for you to decide.  how to save a token exactly after payment? -after you process the paypal payment save it in your database. I mean how to reference it back? save it with a hashed timestamp or something and bound the database row with the user id, so when the page is reach just search for the user id that corresponds to the hashed timestamp. one can simply refresh the page right? this will stop that if you check in the database for the token each time the processing page is reached